# Is there any tool which can help me to import my .msg files into PDF format?

Tags: pdf, email, file-converter, outlook

I have approximately 1500 .msg files in my system, but now I'm not using Outlook as my email client and want to convert all .msg files into PDF format, because PDF is very easy to use and I can access that anywhere, any-time. Is there any software which can import my .msg file into PDF without destroying them?

Answer (score 1):

THE one tool I use for such cases is [**MSGConvert**](https://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/):

- it converts `.msg`-files into **`.eml`-files**.
  *this is IMHO even better than just `.pdf`, because the header is kept and you can still create `.pdf`s or anything else you want.*
- it is a pretty straight forward **command line** tool and can therefore easily be used for batch converting, scripting etc.
- it does **not need** an installed version of **MS Outlook**.
- it just **needs Perl** as dependency and is therefore **cross platform** available.
- it does not destroy anything because the original files are only read.
- it may not convert the `.msg`-files completely perfect, but hardly any tool (I tested) does. - thank you Microsoft!
  *disclaimer: if your life depends on these e-mails, I would keep the original files anyways (no matter what tool you use), because they are called "original" for a reason. - especially when converting complex proprietary binary formats (like `.msg`) you should consider it as lossy.*
  e.g. I don't know how [TNEF-attachments](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/what-winmaildat-attachment) are handled and I have no idea if/how such messages can be identified.
- it is **FOSS** (free as in beer and speech) and therefore can be improved and extended by everyone: https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the **free** [Convert MSG to PDF](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookConvertMSG2PDF) utility developed by my company. It automatically converts all MSG files in the selected folder to Adobe PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

PstViewer Pro from Encryptomatic can do this.

https://www.encryptomatic.com/pstviewer/

Comment: Welcome Nemo! Can you please add a link to your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I will. I did try to include a link originally but that caused the whole answer to be rejected as potential spam!

Comment: Thanks.  That's interesting to learn.  My guess is because the answer is short, and it included a link, the SE systems automatically assumed (hopefully incorrectly!) that you post was spam.  I think another factor may have been that you are new to our community.  In any case, it looks like you were now allowed to post a link.  Just to be sure, you don't have any affiliation with Encryptomatic, do you?  If you do, that's okay, but we require that you add your affiliation to your post.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: No affiliation to Encryptomatic or any other provider of software.